# Reduce method fails asking to yield block even though block given

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I have a class that I've included the `Enumerable` module as follows:

```
class Paragraph
  include Enumerable
  attr_accessor :error_totals

  def initialize(text, error_totals)
    @original  = text   
    @error_totals = error_totals
  end

  def each
    error_totals.each {|category, total| yield category, total }
  end

  def totals
     each.reduce(0) {|t,(category,total)| to += total }
  end
end
```

I get the following error and I don't understand why:

```
LocalJumpError:
  no block given (yield)
```

However when I do the following it works:

```
def total_errors_per(number_of_words:)
  result = 0.0
  each {|category, total| result += total.to_f/original.word_count*number_of_words}
  result
end
```

Why does reduce cause this problem? I am passing a block after the call to reduce. I really would like to understand how to use the Enumerable module properly via understanding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your `each` implementation you call `yield` no matter whether the block was given or not, and in `each.reduce` call `each` receives *no block*.

One should return an enumerator if no block was given:

```
def each
  return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?
  error_totals.each {|category, total| yield category, total }
end
```

Comment: I thought that if no block is given an enumerator object is returned automatically

Comment: Nothing is being done automatically in computer science. CPU understands processing instructions, not your wishes and dreams.

Comment: Not true. According to The Well Grounded Rubyist by David Black, pg 316 "Most built in iterators return an enumerator when they're called without a block"

Comment: And this is exactly what my code does. Check any open source library that implements an enumerator.

Comment: I meant no checking should be required according to the documentation. Not my hopes or dreams

Comment: “no checking should be required according to the documentation”—please refer to the documentation, not to some unknown offline resource.

Comment: For your information The Well -Grounded Rubyist is one of the premier Ruby books on the market. It is extremely well known and respected.  Might be worth picking up and have a read.

Comment: Looks like having it read does not help much in understanding basics, and I did not read a single book, save for plain old good documentation, and I inevitably know the solution :)

Comment: @chell “Most **BUILT IN** iterators return an enumerator when they're called without a block”. You wrote your own iterator, that's not built-in.

Comment: Thank @ArieXiao that is the most helpful comment so far.